# dispatch_sync never comes back from the block

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

Hi I have following code, my problem is sometimes it never comes out of the `dispatch_sync` block deadlock situation. I have searched for it however none solution worked. Can any one help to find the reason and sort this out.

```
connectionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("YapDatabaseConnection", NULL);

dispatch_sync(connectionQueue, ^{ @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"read block_sync :started");
        if (longLivedReadTransaction)
        {
      NSLog(@"read block_sync :started1 %@",longLivedReadTransaction);
            block(longLivedReadTransaction);
        }
        else
        {

            YapDatabaseReadTransaction *transaction = [self newReadTransaction];
        NSLog(@"read block_sync :started2 %@",transaction);
            [self preReadTransaction:transaction];
      NSLog(@"read block_sync :1 %@",transaction);
            block(transaction);
      NSLog(@"read block_sync :2 %@",transaction);
            [self postReadTransaction:transaction];
      NSLog(@"read block_sync :3 %@",transaction);
        }
    }});
```

Comment: Assuming you are running this code on the main queue, any call back to,the main queue from your code will cause a deadlock

Comment: yes YapDatabase run on MainThread only and it doesn't happen everytime

Comment: I think you should check stack traces of all threads.

Comment: You should provide more code. For example, what queues are using in the block?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but needless to say, using `dispatch_sync` is rarely a good idea. You’re blocking the thread from which you make this call and inviting deadlocks. But we’re not going to be able to help you in the absence of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).